# I want to know how to check whether a checkbox is checked or not in android from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, checkbox

I want to know how to check whether a checkbox is checked or not when an application is not running. Please help me. I'm making a call blocker, and I'm stuck.

When the application is not running, how can it check whether the checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: Please include some code and a description of what you've tried

Answer (score 1):

Android provides [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) class which is an utility that helps you to save user settings within your app internal memory and can be accessed by providing your application context.

Let's say that the user has checked the checkbox control, you could save that choice using **SharedPreferences** instance saving it onto disk.

For example:

```
myCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = yourActivityContext.getSharedPrefences("user_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor = prefs.edit(); //Create this instance in order to save data

    editor.putBoolean("checked", isChecked); //Store the checkbox value

    editor.commit(); //Call this to save the preferences to disk
   }
```

}
);

Then in your **BroadcastReceiver**:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent data) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("user_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

boolean checkboxValue = prefs.getBoolean("checked", false); 
//The second argument provide a default value if you haven't saved that setting before.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you start an application, a completely new instance of the program is created.  And once the application terminates, the instance that was running no longer exists for you to check its state.

What you will have to do is...

1. Store the settings in a file or database when the program closes (or when the user hits "save" depending on how you design it)
2. When the application opens, have it read the settings and populate the screen (e.g., checkboxes) with its contents

If you didn't write the program that owns the checkbox (which wasn't clear in your original post), then the program must already do this; otherwise, it would have no way to re-populate the screen when it starts up.  In this case, all you have to do is find out what the file or database table stores the info you need and figure out how to extract the data you need from that location.

Answer (score 0):

you can store checkbox value in database or web api and check through Android Services class.

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreferences. In the onCheckChangedListener, just store a shared preferences with the boolean value associated with the checkbox. The broadcast receiver should have the same context, so you should be able to access the shared preference from there.